# How to refer to current cell (or this cell) in conditional format?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, circular-dependency

I'm in cell T6 and use this code:

```
=if(isblank(T6),,1)
```

**so basically if it's not empty then convert to 1**

example: if the user enters 'hi' or 'test' or 123 or whatever except blank spaces then I want the cell value to be 1

The above code is not working as I get  `#REF!` error. If I refer to another cell, it works fine, but if I refer to the current cell, I got an error. The **T6** is the current cell I want to put the script. Can someone show the correct code?

Comment: Is the formula in T6 or in a different cell?

Comment: formule in T6 itself. I've just edited my post. Thanks

Comment: I dont think you can refernece only the same cell like that. The formula will need to go in a differemt cell. Also you can't programmatically set a cell to NULL. Can set it to be just ""

Answer (score 0):

the formula you use is correct. the issue here is that you are creating a circular dependency by referring to a cell from the cell you are in and those happen to be same. the right course of action, in this case, is to use the formula in any other cell than T6 to track the user input of T6.

Comment: Only problem is how do you then change the value of T6 from the new cell? Not sure you can through formulas. Might have to get into scripting

Comment: its possible but only with a script